# SKCameraNode working weird

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a simple `SpriteKit` game. I have a player that starts from the bottom-center of the screen.
I added to my `GameScene` a camera to follow the player but it does not work. when I run it with this code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let mPlayer = Player(circleOfRadius: 45, fillColor: myColors.blue, strokeColor: myColors.red)
    let cameraNode = SKCameraNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        setup()
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        moveCamera()
        Player.movePlayerUp(mPlayer: mPlayer)
    }

    func setup(){
        mPlayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - PLAYER_WIDTH, y: self.frame.minY + PLAYER_HEIGHT)

        self.camera?.position = mPlayer.position

        self.camera = cameraNode
        self.addChild(cameraNode)
        self.addChild(mPlayer)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            mPlayer.run(SKAction.moveTo(x: location.x, duration: 0.1))
        }
    }

    func moveCamera(){
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: mPlayer.position.y, duration: 0.1)
        cameraNode.run(moveAction)
    }
}
```

the player is starting from the bottom and immediately moves to the center of the screen like in this picture:[image]

How can I make the camera to follow the player from the start and move with it to the top?
Hope my question is clear and sorry for the size of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me in a empty Xcode project. You are probably thinking its not because your background image is 1 color and you are only moving the player briefly.

Also in your update method you set to move the player constantly to the middle, which is not necessary.

Try adding some stripes to the background to make it easier to see if you move and than add this code to the update method do slowly move the player up constantly.

```
let action = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 5), duration: 1)
mPlayer.run(action)
```

You will see the camera is following the player correctly.

If you need to center your camera differently to the player e.g on the y axis than you just have to increase/decrease the y position of the camera.

```
 let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: mPlayer.position.y + 200, duration: 0.1)
 cameraNode.run(moveAction)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried to add your code but nothing seem to be different. If the camera is moving, why the background does not to "disappear" slowly from the bottom as the player moves up?

Comment: It is working for me. I copied your code into a new game project and just added some stripes to the background and changed the move method. Everything works correctly. Is your background an image or did you set the scene background color?

Comment: It is a background color. It seems to work but I want the bottom of the screen to "disappear" as the player goes up.

Comment: The background color is not just filling the scene canvas, its everything. So you can move forever and it will always be purple. Add some stripes to the background (SKSpriteNodes) and you will see that it works.

Comment: or add a background image.

Comment: It is working, but I want the player to be lower and not in the center of the screen. How can I do that?

Comment: In your move camera method you just have to increase/decrease the y position. I updated my answer.

Comment: You are very welcome. Do not hesitate to ask another question. Happy coding